# Proving that $f^2$ is differentiable given that f is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

So I've tried using the definition: $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ iff 
$$
f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0)\cdot x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(y_0)\cdot y+o(\sqrt {(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2})
$$
So, trying to prove this relation (substituted $f$ for $f^2$, and performing the chain rule), I got this limit,
$$
\lim_{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} \to 0}
\frac{{(f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0))}^2}{\sqrt {(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}},
$$
which doesn't seem to be going anywhere. Should I go with the definition or perhaps should I try something else?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we write $r:=\vert\vert(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\vert\vert$, differentiability of $f$ is equivalent to the existence of $(a,b)$ such that $f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+o(r)$.

Squaring this gives $f(x,y)^2=f(x_0,y_0)^2+2(a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0))f(x_0,y_0)+(a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0))^2+o(r)$ (noting that $(f(x_0,y_0)+a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0))\times o(r)$ is $o(r)$.

By switching to polar coordinates ($x=x_0+r\cos\theta, y=y_0+r\sin\theta$) we see that$(a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0))^2=r^2(a\cos^2\theta+b\sin^2\theta)=O(r^2)$, and so is definitely $o(r)$, whence:

$$f(x,y)^2=f(x_0,y_0)^2+2(a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0))f(x_0,y_0)+o(r)$$

which by our initial reframing, tells us that $f^2$ is also differentiable at the given point.

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate about (ax+by)2=O(r2)?

Comment: Ah - need to amend slightly, had been working as if $(x_0,y_0)$ was the origin. Will fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is a straightforward consequence of the chain rule. For an elementary solution, you might want to remark that $f^2-g^2=(f-g)(f+g)$. Now choose $f$ and $g$ properly and let $(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Then am I using it right? I mean does partial(f^2)=2f*partial(f) at some point?